# How to add a Click event to a custom WPF WindowTitle

Tags: wpf, events, event-handling, window

I have restyled a WPF window, everything works really well. However, I now need to display a pop-up menu when someone clicks on the title bar. I don't don't understand how I can do this as the title down click is handled by a mouse down in one of borders in the style, and this is generic style that I am applying to several windows?

The window style looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MYWindow" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize" />
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BGBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource FGBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="26"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="26"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="26"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="26"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" BitmapEffect="{StaticResource DropShadow}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>

                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2" ClipToBounds="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>

                    <Border Background="{StaticResource GreyGradientBrush}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" BitmapEffect="{StaticResource WindowTitleShadow}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" MouseDown="HandleTitleBarMouseDown"/>
```

Currently HandleTitleBarMouseDown handles the dragging of the window as follows:

```
  partial class MYStyles
  {

    public void HandleTitleBarMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
      Window window = GetWindow(sender);

      window.DragMove();
    }
}
```

I re-use the style as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
    Style="{DynamicResource MYWindow}" Title="Test MY Window" Height="599" Width="891" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" WindowStyle="None" Padding="0" MouseDown="">
```

I need to somehow have an event raised in the Window1 class but have no idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use global event hooking.

Put this line in your app.xaml.cs or whatever class is called when you start the application:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Window.PreviewMouseUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnWindowPreviewMouseUp));
```

And declare the OnWindowPreviewMouseUp event handler:

```
void OnWindowPreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //do your implementation
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MouseMove` event for dragging:

```
 private void HandleTitleBar_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
     {
         Window window = GetWindow(sender);
         window.DragMove();
      }
 }
```

Then you can use `MouseDown` event to show your custom `Popup` with desired content.